# How to use a auto generated ssh key to connect to server with Amazon Lightsail Service through ModulesGarden

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, amazon-lightsail, whmcs, cloud-hosting

I'm implementing the Whmcs application through Amazon Lightsail ModulesGarden, following the [Amazon Lightsail For WHMCS](https://www.docs.modulesgarden.com/Amazon_Lightsail_For_WHMCS#SSH_Keys) document guide. In the setting step, I turned on the Auto Generate SSH Key mode. After placing an order successfully I got a detailed invoice and in the database inserted automatically an ssh key record. However I don't know the right way to use it to connect to the server.
I trying to copy the value in the private_key column and paste into a new file and use it like a RSA file.
[image]

```
$ ssh -i ssh_rsa <username>@<public IP>
output: Load key "ssh_rsa": invalid format
```